# Change columnWidth in Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I wish to change masonry's column width on resize.

I init masonry with:

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            columnWidth: $('#container').width() / 4,
        });
```

Then on resize I try:

```
$(window).on("debouncedresize", function( event ) {
    $container.masonry( 'option', { columnWidth: $('#container').width() / 4 });

});
```

But the above appears to have no effect. Any ideas?

Edit:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1ayh1nv/)

I made a fiddle and it appears to work, the difference being using the standard window resize in the fiddle and in my code ive used the plugin debouncedresize.

This fires only when the window has completed resizing, this must be causing the issue, any ideas how to fix?

Comment: can you please create a sample on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: updated original question with fiddle

Comment: its actually working fine without `debouncedresize` :D

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla yes, that appears to be the problem, but wouldn't it be better to debounce the window resize, otherwise it's constantly updating the column width?

Comment: depends on how much content you have on the page and how often would resize be called

Comment: It would be called alot. How can I get masonry to work with a debounce method?